# Python Problems with exec

Tags: python, exec

I call

```
exec(compile(open(self.filename, "rb").read(), self.filename, 'exec'))
```

in the init method of my entity class, which loads spider.py:

```
import util, colors, random

self.dtouch = False

def touch2(self, entity):
    self.level.ps.add_particle(self.get_rect().x + random.randint(0, 31), self.get_rect().y + random.randint(0, 31), 0, -5, 2, 2, colors.RED, 500 + random.randint(0, 50))
```

and when the player touches the spieder, I call `touch2(entity)` in my orginal touch method to execute the code in the touch2 method from spider.py.
But when I do this, I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'touch2' is not defined
```

Does anyone know, how I can call the method from the other class I loaded in init?

Edit: Import Lib doesn't work... Can someone tell me how I can fix that error and use the method from the class which I loaded which exec?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just import it - you can use `importlib` if you need to import a file with a dynamic name?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are reading the file instead of importing it. Change this line

```
exec(compile(open(self.filename, "rb").read(), self.filename, 'exec'))
```

to

```
import spider
```

Hope this helps :)

**Update:**

As mentioned by @DanielRoseman in the comments, if you use the `importlib` module (which I personally have no experience with so I sadly can't help) you should be able to import it using the `self.filename` instead of having to use `spider`.